# Is it safe for a pregnant lady to go to Hokkaido in 2016?

Tags: japan, safety, health, event-based-effects, hokkaido

Fukushima incident causes a lot of fears among people, as to whether it's safe for tourists to go to Japan or not.

While I understand that the radiation [is not a problem for normal people](https://www.worldnomads.com/travel-safety/eastern-asia/japan/how-dangerous-is-the-radiation-in-japan), what about a pregnant lady who wants to go to hokkaido ? Will the radiation cause cancer or problem to either the pregnant lady or the baby?

Comment: Assuming by "safe" you mean below government recommended limits?

Comment: @CMaster, "safe" as in normal sense

Comment: there is no normal sense. People have wildly varying levels of acceptable risk, and some persons have different levels of acceptable risk for different hazards. Unless you plan to tour Fukushima Dachi, the radiation riks is almost certainly safer for the pregnant woman (and child) than putting her in a car. For that reason we like people to describe what counts as "safe" to them (or to just ask broadly about the risk level), otherwise the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Even visiting the Fukushima area (outside of the plant itself) is perfectly safe despite whatever the media says. Same goes for Chernobyl - only a very small area is actually dangerous for short-term visitors.

Comment: @JonathanReez although it is worth noting that pregnant women are advised to subject themselves to *much* lower doses than the population at large. Although noones ever done an RCT to determine how much lower, mind.

Comment: @CMaster, if the risk is safer than putting her in a car, that would counted as "safe". You can answer the question along that definition

Comment: Pretty much everything is safer than driving, including commercial flying above a war zone.

Comment: This is not primarily opinion-based. This is primarily SCIENCE-based! :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**It's safe.** Per both the [Japan Radiation Map](http://jciv.iidj.net/map/list) and [Safecast](http://safecast.org/tilemap/?y=42.9&x=141.63&z=7), radiation levels in Hokkaido are safe (green) at less than 0.05 microSieverts (μSv) per hour, or 1.2 μSv/day.

For comparison, if you live in a brick or concrete house you get a dose of [about 70 μSv/year](http://www.pbs.org/wnet/need-to-know/the-daily-need/how-much-radiation-is-too-much-a-handy-guide/8124/), and if you spend 14 hours on a plane, you will get a dose of [around 100 μSv](http://www.traveller.com.au/flight-risk-how-much-radiation-do-planes-expose-you-to-1a54m) from atmospheric radiation.

Comment: Even in the most elevated areas, you could stay over a month amd still stay under annual does limits - although obviously different for pregnant women.  Other than the Fukashima plant site itself, are the elevated levels in Fukushima perfecture a consqeuence of the power plant, or is there just a lot of granite there?

Comment: I expect the levels are a lot lower then Dartmoor (UK) and lots of people are happy to go on holiday to Dartmoor.

Comment: For another relevant comparison (also from [Randall Munroe’s great chard](https://xkcd.com/radiation/)), a typical mammogram is 400µSv — as much as a year in Hokkaido, at the rates reported in above.  And there’s plenty of medical advice out there about getting mammograms during pregnancy, generally (as far as I can find) reporting that [it’s pretty safe](http://www.cancer.org/cancer/breastcancer/moreinformation/pregnancy-and-breast-cancer).