# Is it safe to travel around Japan when pregnant, regarding radiation?

Tags: japan, health, pregnancy

We are considering travelling to Japan in May. Maybe I'm pregnant on the journey. 
We plan to travel around Tokyo, Kyoto and the countryside.

Will radiation be too dangerous during pregnancy?

Comment: Do you mean after the Fukashima incident? If so I recommend reading [Is it safe to travel in Japan considering the nuclear situation?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-it-safe-to-travel-in-japan-considering-the-nuclear-situation?rq=1) - nothing specific about pregnancy, but it gets across the distances and incredibly low levels of radiation in the kinds of places you're talking about

Comment: Also even more relevant is [Is it safe for a pregnant lady to go to Hokkaido in 2016?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68984/is-it-safe-for-a-pregnant-lady-to-go-to-hokkaido-in-2016?rq=1) - Hokkaido isn't much further from Fukashima than Tokyo is, and the link can give you up to date info on any destination in Japan

Comment: There are numerous sources you could consult, but ultimately what you class as "safe" is up to your interpretation. The vast majority of pregnant females in Japan who have not or who do not live near the Fukushima Daiichi Nuclear plant have not shown any irregularities from the norm. For comparison, in general the US Midwest has higher background radiation than both Tokyo, Kyoto and Western Japans rural areas. Daily measurements comparing current readings with those pre-Fukushima can be found here: http://radioactivity.nsr.go.jp/en/list/192/list-1.html

Answer (score -1):

See below to help you make your judgment. Traveling while pregnant should be your paramount concern, with the radiation a distant second based on this article.

**Is it safe to visit Japan?**

That depends on whom you ask and what areas of Japan you’re talking about.

http://www.webmd.com/cancer/features/japan-nuclear-plant-radiation-risks-faq#visit

As of **March 30, 2011** the U.S. State Department still advised people to defer non-essential travel to a number of regions beyond just the area of the earthquake, tsunami and radiation crisis, including Tokyo and Yokohama.

Other popular destinations, such as Kyoto, Okinawa and Osaka, are ***“outside the regions of concern,”*** according to the State Department’s warning. (For an updated alert, go to the State Department's web site.)

On the other hand, experts tell WebMD that they would not hesitate to travel to areas of Japan outside the disaster zone.

“I was supposed to go to Japan next month, but the meeting was cancelled because the organizers understandably have other things to do,” Williams (**radiation biologist Jacqueline P. Williams, PhD, tells WebMD. Williams is a researcher in the department of radiation oncology at the University of Rochester, N.Y.**) says. “But I was perfectly happy to go, and I’m a bit sad that I’m not because I’ve never been to Japan. I would be absolutely fine to go.”

Comment: That is exactly the reason why I do not need more recent info. The decay of radiation with time.

Comment: FYI, the [US State Department Travel Alert concerning Fukushima Daiichi](http://web.archive.org/web/20120411223212/http://travel.state.gov/travel/cis_pa_tw/pa/pa_5574.html) expired on April 13, 2012.